# Google Analytics considers app updates as new installations

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-analytics

Does Google Analytics count app updates as new installations?. Is there a way to find out?

I want real new users to get into the "new users" section. When I release an update in my app, the number of users in Google Analytics sometimes increases.

Thanks.